# How to extract original file data from OLE attachment in Outlook using C# VSTO add-in?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on a VSTO add-in for Outlook in C#, and I need to extract the original file from an OLE attachment. The user has attached a file (such as a Word document or Excel spreadsheet) as an OLE object to an email, and I need to access the original data that was embedded into the OLE object.

I've tried using the Attachment.PropertyAccessor to retrieve the attachment data, but I'm getting an "Invalid OLE structured storage file" error. I've also tried using the OpenMcdf library to extract the embedded object data, but I'm not sure how to map the byte array to the original file.

Is there a way to access the original file data from an OLE attachment in Outlook using C#? Can I use an event in Outlook to read the original data before it's converted to an OLE object? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the Outlook Object Model. In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you can open the attachment as an `IStorage` object (`IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ, IStorage, ...)`), then extract the data, but its format depends on the OLE server used to create it - you can see the data in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - select the message, click IMessage button, double click on the attachment on the GetAttachmentTable tab, select the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property, select IMAPIProp::OpenProperty | IStorage).

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am also its author), it version of [RDOAttachment](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`SaveAs` handles OLE storage attachments for the most popular formats (Word, Excel, Power Point, PDF, etc.)

Comment: Trying to use Redemption, the SaveAsFile saves the OLE Attachment as oledata.mso, still not the original file, which is a pdf file. Can you provide me with further informations to get to the original file?

Comment: oledata.mso is how Outlook stores OLE objects nowadays in HTML emails - you get an HTML email, but the attachments are still regular by-value attachments, not OLE.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model applies restrictions on the amount of data that can be read using the `PropertyAccessor` object. You need to use the low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or any other third-party wrappers around that API such as Redemption (like Dmitry mentioned already) for reading the attachment's binary array (content). The `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property holds the attachment when the value of the `PR_ATTACH_METHOD` property is `ATTACH_EMBEDDED_MSG` or `ATTACH_OLE`. The OLE encoding type can be determined from `PR_ATTACH_TAG`.

The best what you could do with the Outlook object model is to save the file on the disk using the [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method and then reading it back.